# laravel nested db transaction doesnt commit

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, transactions, database-connection

I have a nested transaction that uses to commit few different tables. I only want to commit one table in the nested and the other two tables in the outer commit.

```
beginTransaction();

error_message.=function A();
error_message.=function B();

if (empty error_message){
    commit(); //commit table B and C
} else {
    rollback();
}
```

```
function A(){
    beginTransaction();
    update table A //wants to commit table A immediately
    commit();
    //do some stuff
    update table B
    if(error) {
        return error_message
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

function B(){
    beginTransaction();
    update table A //wants to commit table A immediately
    commit();
    //do some stuff
    update table C
    if(error) {
        return error_message
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call beginTransaction(); before the function, there will be two `beginTransaction();` first is outside of the function and second is inside the function.

```
beginTransaction();
error_message.=function A();
error_message.=function B();
```

Put your beginTransaction(); below the function call.

```
error =0;

error_message = function A();
if(empty(error_message)){
   error =1;
}

error_message = function B();
if(empty(error_message)){
   error =1;
}

beginTransaction();
if (error){
    commit(); //commit table B and C
} else {
    rollback();
}
```

Comment: this will still update table B and C without checking whether error_message is empty

Comment: are  you sure you check your error this type. `if(empty(error_message))`

Comment: yes. each of the function will update the table and return error_message no matter it is empty or not

Comment: this is what my problem is. I don't want my table to be updated immediately in each of the function. I would like to wait till there is no error only update

Comment: i have 3 tables to be updated, only one table i wan to update immediately but the other 2 i wan to wait till no error only update

Answer (score 0):

i think in you miss rollback() in write function a() or b().

```
rollback()
```

and dbtransaction is not running when you skip 1 methods of 3

```
1 beginTransaction()//start transection
2 commit()//commit your transaction
3 rollback()//rollback your transaction
```

without rollback beginTransaction not working.

and i think you miss ()after empty